# \mathsf with different typeface

Tags: stix, sansmathfonts

For fonts in math mode, I am using package `stix2` like

```
\usepackage[notext]{stix2}
```

As expected, this changes the default (sans-serif) font for `\mathsf`. But I would like to use `\mathsf` with the font from the sans-serif Computer Modern typeface that LaTeX uses by default (that is, the font for `\mathsf` if there were no `\usepackage[notext]{stix2}` at all), while keeping with the rest of `stix2` fonts in math mode. How can I do this?

I've been looking here through previous questions on TeX Stack Exchange and I have found nothing related.

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX? Then, running `\usepackage{unicode-math} \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}` will change the serif math font but not the sans-serif math font face.

Answer (score 4):

The `\mathsf` alphabet from `sansmathfonts` is the `cmssm` family, using NFSS.  It’s in the OML encoding, which supports both Latin and Greek.  You can select it through the `isomath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notext]{stix2}
\usepackage[OMLmathsfit,sfdefault=cmssm]{isomath}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathsfit{y} = \mathsfit{\alpha x} + \mathsfit{\beta} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: sansmathfonts + stix2 sample]

If you want to use both an upright `\mathsf` and an italic `\mathsfit` in the same document, you can define them with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`.  In that case, you would want the OT1 or T1 version of the `xcmss` family as your upright font.  There is no upright font in `sansmathfonts` with lowercase Greek letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notext]{stix2}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{xcmss}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{xcmss}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{OML}{cmssm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{OML}{cmssm}{b}{it}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathsfit{y} = \mathsfit{\alpha x} + \mathsfit{\beta} + \mathsf{\Phi x_0} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: sansmathfonts + stix2 sample]

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load OpenType fonts through `unicode-math`. Unicode does not support sans-serif Greek.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMSans10-Book}[
  range=sfup,
  script-font={NewCMSans08-Book},
  script-features={}, % Suppress a harmless warning.
  sscript-font={NewCMSans08-Book},
  sscript-features={},
  Extension=.otf]
\setmathfont{NewCMSans10-BookOblique}[
  range=sfit,
  script-font={NewCMSans08-BookOblique},
  script-features={},
  sscript-font={NewCMSans08-BookOblique},
  sscript-features={},
  Extension=.otf]

\begin{document}
\[ \symsfit{y} = \symsfit{\alpha x} + \symsfit{\beta} + \symsfup{\Phi x_0} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Sans/STIX Two Math sample]

Or perhaps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}[
  range={sfup,sfit,bfsfup,bfsfit}]

\begin{document}
\[ \symsfit{y} = \symsfit{\alpha x} + \symsfit{\beta} + \symsfup{\Phi x_0} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Math/STIX Two Math sample]

It is possible to define a sans-serif Greek alphabet in `unicode-math` with `\setmathsf` or `\setmathfontface`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}[
  range={sfup,sfit,bfsfup,bfsfit}]

\setmathfontface\varsfup{NewCMSans10-Regular.otf} % Can define SizeFeatures for subscripts.
\setmathfontface\varsfit{NewCMSans10-Oblique.otf}

\begin{document}
\[ \symsfit{y} = \varsfit{\mupalpha} \symsfit{x} + \varsfit{\mupbeta} + \varsfup{\mupPhi} \symsfup{x_0} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: NewCMMath + NewCMSans + STIX Two Math sample]

If you use `\mathsf` extensively in your document, you might want to load `unicode-math` with the `[sf=sym]` package option, for backward compatibility.  This means that, if you ever have code like `\mathsf{cosine}` in your document, you should change it to `\textsf`, or change your operator font with `\setoperatorfont`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd never use the `notext` option to `stix2`: you get a very strange mix of fonts.

Anyway, here's how you can solve your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[notext]{stix2}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

This is text and we have math
$a+b=\mathsf{C}$ {\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just as a check, here's the output if I comment out the loading of `stix2`.

[image]